# Ext JS: How to show logo.png file in resources folder?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am new in Ext JS and studying Gerald Gierrer book on Enterprise Application Development with ExtJS and Spring - Chapter 10. After generating the Ext JS 4.2.2 application. I have copied the resources folder `.png` and `.ico` files into the newly generated application.
I have no idea how those images and icons can be shown on the panels.

Following is the `LogonWindow`. How to make the logo-small being shown when the program is running:

```
Ext.define("TTT.view.LogonWindow", {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'logonwindow',
    closable: false,
    iconCls: 'logo-small',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Task Time Tracker Logon',
    requires: ['Ext.form.field.Text'],
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
```

The next one is in the MainHeader, The logo.png is kept in `resources\images`. But It doesn't show up in the `MainHeader`.

```
Ext.define('TTT.view.MainHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'mainheader',
    requires: ['Ext.toolbar.Toolbar'],
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                cls: 'logo',
                width: 300
            }, {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
```

Any clue on how to handle this?

Comment: You can use xtype:image as window item and give its source(image path) to src config of this image.

Comment: Did you include the "logo-small" and "logo" css rule definitions somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for not responding directly. I was away from my system for a week due to holiday.

Comment: I actually don't know how to use xtype image and how to set it up in src config.

Comment: Can you give some sample so that I can understand? Thanks beforehand.